# RegExp to match anyname/anynamewithid/date/string

Tags: python, regex, django, pattern-matching, regexp-substr

I want to write a regular expression to match the given pattern

## ***anyname/anyname2/anydate/string***

**anyname**: It must accept valid names including underscore (_)

**anyname2**: It must accept valid names including underscore(_) or hiffen (-)

**anydate**: The date must be in the format like 'yyyy-mm-dd'. Ex: 2016-12-10

**string**: This string contains predefined strings. it needs to match only the required characters like, [computer],[desktop],[laptop]. Other than these 3, it should not match any other.

**Note**: The expression must also match '/' as in the above mentioned pattern

Comment: have you try it yourself? please post you code

Comment: Which part of it are you having trouble with?  What is a "valid name"?

Comment: What means "valid names" and what means characters like "[computer]"? Computer is not a character.

Comment: computer is at string.
I have some limited strings, which need to match in that exp

Comment: "valid names" means example: dhruva/jagadamba_junction
Rules are it should not contain any special characters except _

Comment: Some examples of inputs which should pass and should fail would be helpful.  If you could describe which part you are having trouble with and what you have already tried, that would be helpful too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirements aren't terribly clear, but if I understand them correctly, then something like the following should work:

```
\w+/[\w\-]+/\d{4}-[01]\d-[0-3]\d/(computer|desktop|laptop)
```